# Rx (RxJS) group Observable stream according to an array of keys

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

I am using RxJS to group the results of an AJAX API call (Google Knowledge Graph) according to a type key. Each result item may contain multiple types. The results look like this:

```
const data = [
    { name: 'item1', types:['A', 'B']},
    { name: 'item2', types:['C', 'D']},
    { name: 'item3', types:['A', 'B', 'C']},
    { name: 'item4', types:['B']},
    { name: 'item5', types:['B', 'C']},
    { name: 'item6', types:['A', 'D']},
    { name: 'item7', types:['B', 'C']},
];
```

My approach to achieving this is to flatten the results so that each element contains one type key only to be able to use the built-in operator `groupBy`.

```
Rx.Observable.from(data)
  .flatMap(item => {
    return item.types
      .map(type => Object.assign({}, item, {type}) );
  })
  .groupBy(item => item.type)
  .subscribe(type => {
    type.count().subscribe(count => console.log(`${count} items has type ${type.key}`));
  });
```

The results will transform into something like:

```
{ name: 'item1', type:'A'},
{ name: 'item1', type:'B'},
{ name: 'item2', type:'c'},
...
```

And the output will be:

```
3 items has type A
5 items has type B
4 items has type C
2 items has type D
```

This achieves the desired behavior, but I am not sure if duplicating the items is the most efficient approach to use with a live stream of large data before completion. I also assume that this is a common use case so I wonder if there is another built-in operator to achieve this that I missed in the API doc. I'd love to get some input or suggestions.

The above example is available at https://jsfiddle.net/t9Ls1p2f/

Comment: well, you could do the same with a combination of `scan` and `last`, could be more efficient but that could only be checked by testing.